# android two-way data binding for checkbox using int

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a User data class as below and I need to use two-way data binding for the checkbox using the active variable.

- active == 1, check
- active == 0, uncheck

`data class User( var name: String, var active: Int )`

`android:checked="@={viewModel.user.active == 1}"`

I tried this and two-way data binding does not support this. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
android:checked="@={viewModel.user.active == 1}
```

**TO**

```
android:checked="@{type == 1? true : false}
```

Comment: I need two-way binding. when checked active variable should change to 1 and when unchecked active variable should change to 0